# Remove Table Header And Border In Aspose word .NET

Tags: .net, ms-word, tabular, mailmerge, aspose

I am working on a project which need a report from a word template. I need to remove the table header and border when there is no data. I tried many ways but working working any of them.

My template in like below:

[image: Input]

Output is like below:

[image: Output]

I want to remove table design on point 2.

My code is like below

```
DataTable dtPersonalInfo = new dalCoro_Report().GetNonEffCertPersonalInfo(MemberID);
        DataTable dtUnitAppt = new dalCoro_Report().GetNonEffCertExperienceUnitAppt(MemberID);
        DataTable dtCourseInfo = new dalCoro_Report().GetNonEffCertExperienceCourse(MemberID);
        DataTable dtMedalInfo = new dalCoro_Report().GetNonEffCertExperienceMedal(MemberID);
        DataTable dtUnMissionInfo = new dalCoro_Report().GetNonEffCertUN_MSN(MemberID);

        if (dtPersonalInfo.Rows.Count == 0)
            return;

        var fileName = "ExperienceCert_" + dtPersonalInfo.Rows[0]["PersonalNo"] + ".doc";
        var input = Server.MapPath(@"~\Coro_Report\Template\Certificates\6. Experience Cert2.doc");
        var output = Server.MapPath(@"~\Coro_Report\Report\" + fileName);

        var doc = new Document(input);


        dtPersonalInfo.TableName = "PersonalInfo";
        doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(dtPersonalInfo);

        if (dtUnitAppt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            doc.MailMerge.TrimWhitespaces = false;

            dtUnitAppt.TableName = "UnitAppt";
            //doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(dtUnitAppt);
        }

        if (dtCourseInfo.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            doc.MailMerge.TrimWhitespaces = false;

            dtCourseInfo.TableName = "Course";
            doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(dtCourseInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            doc.MailMerge.RemoveEmptyRegions = true;
        }

        if (dtMedalInfo.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            doc.MailMerge.TrimWhitespaces = false;

            dtMedalInfo.TableName = "Medal";
            doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(dtMedalInfo);
        }

        if (dtUnMissionInfo.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            doc.MailMerge.TrimWhitespaces = false;
            dtUnMissionInfo.TableName = "UnMission";
            doc.MailMerge.ExecuteWithRegions(dtUnMissionInfo);
        }


        doc.MailMerge.CleanupOptions = MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveUnusedRegions | MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveUnusedFields | MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveContainingFields | MailMergeCleanupOptions.RemoveEmptyParagraphs;

        doc.MailMerge.DeleteFields();

        //Save the document
        doc.Save(output);

        ViewReport(fileName);
```

Comment: It looks like you can't attach files in this forum. We need to test this scenario on our end. So, please create a new post in [Aspose.Words forum](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). Please zip and attach your 1) input Word file, 2) Aspose.Words generated output Word document, 3) your Expected Word document and simplified Console Application (source code without compilation errors) in your thread for testing. We will investigate the scenario on our end and provide you more information. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it in Aspose, but maybe you can try creating two parts of the document (one with non empty table and one with empty table/without table).

Then you could solve it the same way how it's solved in Templater, you can see example: https://github.com/ngs-doo/TemplaterExamples/tree/master/Intermediate/WordDataTable%20(.NET)